# Why does Hibernate igore FetchMode.SUBSELECT when an @PostLoad annotation is present

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have to map a (very much not normalized) DB Schema into hibernate, and for various reasons I need to use callback methods to "parse" collections of rows into business objects.

Here is a simplified example of how my mapping looks like:

```
@Table(name = "CONTAINER")
class Container {
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "CONTAINER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
  @MapKey(name = "key")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  private Map<Longs, MappedAttribute> mappedAttributes;

  @Transient
  private BusinessAttribute businessAttribute;

  @PostLoad
  private void postLoad(){
    this.businessAttribute = new BusinessAttribute(mappedAttributes);
  }
}

@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTES")
class MappedAttribute {
  ...
}

class BusinessAttribute {
  public BusinessAttribute(List<MappedAttribute> args){}
}
```

The mapping itself works, and I get the business objects I want in the end, but what puzzles me is the SQL queries that Hibernate used to fetch the relevant rows (simplified you'll get the gist of it):

```
-- First select the root objects
select * from CONTAINER where ID in (1,2,3,4); 
-- Then select all the attribute rows for each root object in individual queries
select * from ATTRIBUTES where CONTAINER_ID = 1;
select * from ATTRIBUTES where CONTAINER_ID = 2;
select * from ATTRIBUTES where CONTAINER_ID = 3;
select * from ATTRIBUTES where CONTAINER_ID = 4;
```

This behavior looks a lot like what would happen if I had specified `FetchMode.SELECT`. Unfortunately that is unacceptable to me, because I will typically have to load a couple thousand containers, and that would generate too many SQL queries. To avoid this I have explicitly specified `FetchType.EAGER` and `FetchMode.SUBSELECT`, but they seem to be ignored.

Note that I am also not touching any of the persistent properties of any of my objects in the `postLoad()` method, as I'm only setting an `@Transient` property.

Interestingly, if I simply comment out the `@PostLoad` annotation, then the queries look like I would have expected (but of course, my business object is not created):

```
--  First select the root objects
select * from CONTAINER where ID in (1,2,3,4);
-- The select all the attributes for all root objects at once
select * from ATTRIBUTES where CONTAINER_ID in (
    select ID from CONTAINER where ID in (1,2,3,4)
);
```

Is there any reason that the Hibernate 5.2.12 EntityManager decides to ignore `FetchMode.SUBSELECT` when callbacks are present?

And is there any way I get the both the callbacks and the subselect behavior at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is the result of a bug in Hibernate, which was reported as [HHH-12279](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12279).

The source of the problem is that the `@PostLoad` annotated method is called after all the basic properties of the entity have been loaded, but before any association has been fully loaded.

What happens in the example above, is that the `mappedAttributes` property is 
not null, but its contents have not been loaded from the DB at the time the `@PostLoad` method is called. At that point calling any getter method on that collection triggers the lazy loading of the elements of that collection.

Since there are multiple `Container` entities and each `Container` has its own collection of children, each collection of children triggers its own SQL `select` query.

I have tried many workarounds (Interceptor, EventListener, Integrator, etc...), but have found none that works (other than manually calling `postLoad()` after gettings the entities back from Hibernate).  The alternatives that didn't work all displayed the same behavior (probably because they are all hooking into the same lifecyle).